# Convert vector of vector of strings to numpy array of objects in cython

Tags: python, cython

Is there a good way to do this? I am trying to do something like

```
pydata = numpy.PyArray_SimpleNew(2, <numpy.npy_intp*> shape, numpy.NPY_OBJECT) # (1)
# then do some sort of memcpy
```

or

```
pydata = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, <numpy.npy_intp*> shape, numpy.NPY_OBJECT, data) # (2)
```

But am getting segfaults even on the pure creation line (1). I think I am going about something in the wrong way. The other approach is to create a python (numpy) object in C++ but I was hoping to keep the interaction with the python api within the cython code.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I am having a look at pandas/parser.pyx to see if there is something I can scam off there but I think the approach to pushing data into python objects is slightly different.

Comment: It seems like simply doing "data = numpy.array(c_vov_data, dtype=str)" works. There is some magic going on that is a bit scary. Not sure what it is doing if the data is not square. I imagine aggregating a char** in C and calling the API from cython has got to be preferred.